# Windows Server 2012R2 blue screen during installation directly after Windows logo appears

Tags: bsod, mbr, windows-server-2012-r2, dell-precision

Installing Server 2012R2 on a Dell Precision T7400 with 14GB of RAM, 2x Intel Xeon X5450 Processors, and an 8400GS. Using a 32GB Sandisk USB, I burned the ISO from the Microsoft website, using Rufus. I had to use the MBR/BIOS mode as my server does not support UEFI.

If I boot from the USB stick, the installation screen does the "Loading Windows" or similar message with the bar. Once the bar hits the end, a split second of the Windows logo appears before restarting.

Does anyone know if any settings need to be changed to fix this?

I have tried burning the ISO under GPT and have re-burned it as MBR twice. I do not have any DVDs at the moment.

Update: Got past the Windows logo, though it went straight to a blue screen. Blue screen went by fast, will try to video it and see what it says.

Update 2: Could not see what it said.

Comment: Try using something other than Rufus.  Maybe etcher?

Comment: Etcher says the ISO is not bootable so I'll redownload it. Cannot actually use Etcher as it has no MBR option.

Comment: You could try this one too: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/windows-usb-dvd-download-tool

Comment: Doesn't have an option for MBR.

Comment: It's been a while since I've done this, but one other thing I vaguely remembered was that you had to boot up with the USB Drive connected to a USB2.0 port, not USB3.  Can you check that?

Comment: The drive itself is USB 3, though all of the ports are USB2. Not sure if this matters, as this drive installed 8.1 on two different computers just fine.

Comment: USB3 drives are backwards compatible with USB2 ports, so that should be fine.  I would suggest checking the checksum of the ISO you downloaded to ensure it's not corrupt.  Last suggestion would be to skip USB altogether and use a DVD instead.  Sometimes that's the only thing that works.

Comment: Got it. The new file just finished downloading and I'll burn it after checking the checksum.

Comment: Did burning a new copy of the file solve your problem?

Comment: Nope! Discovered that my Xeons were stepping A and stepping 6. Already ordered another one and plan on installing a web server after it arrives.